# ajax success : function(response) returns null

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have the following function that deletes a user from my database using a Web API
the server side function returns a string to show whether the user was found and deleted or the user id was not found, it returns a "string" type,

following is the ajax function

```
function deleteuser() {

        var id = $('#<%=txtDelete.ClientID %>').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<%=Page.ResolveUrl("/api/User/")%>" + id,
            type: "DELETE",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
                getAllContacts();
            },

            error: function (x, e) {
                alert(x.responseText);
                alert(e.toString());
                alert('fail');
                getAllContacts();

            }, async: true
        });
```

the problem is that when I call the deleteuser() function, the alerted response returned is always null

Comment: Show your server side code returning the value

Answer (score 0):

The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend use the POST http method,DELETE is not supported by all browsers.